# Use registered variables in other roles

Tags: ansible

Hello guys I have a Problem.

The Problem I am having at the moment, is that the role to copy the files will skip all the files no matter if the file with the filenames is empty or not.

In Role1 I want to save the output of cat for each file. In Role2 in the when conditional, I want the task to skip if the registered output is == "".

Role1:

```
---
- name: copy files
  shell: "cat path{{ item }}files"
  register: checkempty
  loop:
    - test1
    - test2
    - test3
    - test4
```

Role2:

```
---
- name: Copy Files
  copy:
    src: "{{ var1 }}{{ var2 }}{{ var3 }}{{ var4 }}{{ item }}/"
    dest: "{{ copy_dest_sys }}" #destination path
  loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'pathtofile/file').split('\n')}}"
  when: hostvars['localhost'].checkempty.results == ""
```

Playbook:

```
- name: check emptiness
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - ../variables/varsfile
  roles:
    - ../variables/role1

- name: Copy Files to prod/stag
  hosts: "{{hosts_exec}}"
  become: yes
  vars_files:
   - ../vars/recommendation-delta.yml
  roles:
   - ../roles/role2
```

How can I set a registered variable with with_items and compare the output of it to ""(nothing)?
Can somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `register` a variable, it is set only on the specific host on which that task was executing.  So if you are running a role on `localhost` that does this:

```
---
- name: Check if sys files Empty
  command: if [ ! -s filenames/"{{ item }}"files ]; then echo "{{ item }}fileempty"; fi
  register: checkempty
  loop:
    - sys
    - wifi
    - recoprop
    - udfprop
```

Then you would reference it like this when running tasks on another host:

```
hostvars["localhost"].checkempty
```

For example:

```
---
- name: Copy sys Files to prod/stag
  copy:
    src: "{{ git_dest }}{{ git_sys_files }}{{ item }}/"
    dest: "{{ copy_dest_sys }}" #destination path
  loop: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/ansible/repo/hal_ansible/scripts/delta-reco/filenames/sysfiles').split('\n')}}"
  when: 'hostvars["localhost"].checkempty.stdout == "sysfileempty"'
```

You can read more about this in the "[Using Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables)" documentation.

I've made some corrections to your `when` syntax here as well.  In general, you should never use `{{...}}` markers in a `when` condition because a `when` condition is always evaluated as a Jinja expression.

---

However, you have another problem:

Your "Check if sys files Empty" task is using the `command` module, but you're trying to run a shell script. That will always fail.  You need to use the `shell` module instead:

```
---
- name: Check if sys files Empty
  shell: if [ ! -s filenames/"{{ item }}"files ]; then echo "{{ item }}fileempty"; fi
  register: checkempty
  loop:
    - sys
    - wifi
    - recoprop
    - udfprop
```